# Trying to get Random Numbers for Dice Rolls

Tags: c#

I am creating a console RPG game.
I am trying to implement dices.
In this example I have a 6 sided dice.
When pulling a D6 I get a number between 1-6. This is working as intended.
However when I try to use the D6 when creating a strength characteristic I get wierd numbers. I should only be getting numbers that divides evenly by 5, but I am getting random numbers between 0-90..
My Goal is to get a random number between 15-90 in increments of 5's so 15-20-25-30-35-40-45-50-55-60-65-70-75-80-85-90.
What am I missing.
Please advise.

PS: I am new to coding, just started learning this september. So be gentle.

```
 public static int D6()
        {
            int max = (7);
            int min = (1);
            return RNG.rand.Next(min, max);
        }
```

```
public static int STR()
        {
            int getSTR = (D6() + D6() + D6()) *5;
            return RNG.rand.Next(getSTR);
        }
```

I TRIED THIS, BUT GET AN EXCEPTION! (Stack Overflow)

```
public static int STR()
        {
            int getSTR = (D6() + D6() + D6()) *5;
            return RNG.STR();
        }
```

Comment: getSTR will be a number between 1 and 6*5 = 30, so `RNG.rand.Next(getSTR)` will generate a random number between 0 and getSTR. No guarantee that it is a multiple of 5. Side note: adding random numbers will not produce an even distribution, but a more and more centered distribution the more random numbers you add.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal & your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env & data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of screens, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Here you roll 3 times and multiply by 5, next you get random on the result. So you get between 0 and 90-1. Isn't that ? What results do you expect ? Can you add some samples to the question as well as minimum and maximum intended ?

Comment: @KlausGütter - actually `RNG.rand.Next(getSTR)` generates a number between `0` and `getSTR-1`. Ready the documentation more carefully, as the upper limit is exclusive.

Comment: The stackoverflow exception is because a function keeps calling itself infinite times (or when the stack runs out of memory).

Comment: `return RNG.STR()` is an infinite loop... do you want to return `getSTR` ? I finally understand the problem, I think: you do the things right with `int getSTR = (D6() + D6() + D6()) *5` but you don't need to random on this result and just return that, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the downvotes for this question. The OP even stated he/she is new to coding. So downvoters: if you think this question is not OK, help the OP by explaining why and suggest how it can be improved?

Comment: @JohanDonne Downvoting a question is not only related to its quality but also its value and sometimes it may be an opinion. There is a thread on SO Meta; [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question). Also these articles: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: @Olivier Rogier I had read your previous comment and agree with your argument. But I believe it is applied a bit harshly in this case: the OP is (obviously) new to coding, did try to get a result, but did not succeed in finding the error on his/her own. He/she stated the problem clearly, showed what he/she tried, edited the question to improve its formulation and simply asked for advice.

Answer (score 1):

'D6' returns a random number in the range 1..6.   D6()+D6()+D6() will result in a number in the range 3..18. So 'getSTR' will be a multiple of 5 in the range 15 to 90.

and 'RNG.rand.Next(getSTR)' will yield a random number in the range 1.. <the previous found multiple of 5>.

To get a good random multiple of 5 in the range 15..90, use

```
  public static int STR()
  {            
      return  (D6() + D6() + D6()) * 5;;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call the random number generator in `Str` evaluation, since it is called already in `D6`.

This is how I would approach this problem.

```
public static class Utils
{
    private static readonly Random rng = new Random();

    public static int RollDice() => rng.Next(1, 7);

    public static int RollMultiple(int count)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            sum += RollDice();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

public static class Game
{
    public static int CalcStr()
    {
        return 5*Utils.RollMultiple(3);
    }
}
```

---

Alternate methods using LINQ, and also keeping all the rolls in an array

```
public static class Utils
{
    private static readonly Random rng = new Random();

    public static int Roll() => rng.Next(1, 7);

    public static int[] RollMultiple(int count)
        => Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select((i) => Roll()).ToArray();
}

public static class Game
{
    public static int CalcStr()
    {
        return 5*Utils.RollMultiple(3).Sum();
    }
}
```